# What does 0x7fff mean? C language

Tags: c, memory, printf, ip-address

I've made function that prints memory address to the stdout but it dosent work the sameway as printf("%p", ...). For example the printf gives me this: 0x7fff58a2d2bb but my function prints something like this: 58a2d2bb. I know what 0x mean but cant get what 7fff mean. Can someone explain me what does that part mean and how can I add it to my code:

```
char *ft_itoa_base(uintmax_t num, uintmax_t base){
int i;
uintmax_t val_cp;
uintmax_t rem;
char *str;

val_cp = num;
i = 1;
while((val_cp /= base) >= 1)
    i++;
str = ft_strnew(i); // Basically what it does (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 1))
str[i] = '\0';
while(i-- > 0)
{
    rem = num % base;
    str[i] = (rem > 9)? (rem-10) + 'a' : rem + '0';
    num /= base;
}
return (str);}

char a = 'x';
void* p0 = &a;
uintmax_t i = (uintmax_t)p0;
ft_putstr(ft_itoa_base(i, 16));
ft_putchar('\n');
printf("PrintF: %p", p0);
```

Comment: It seems your code is using types that are too short to store addresses in your environment, Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's hexadecimal (base 16).

Comment: You should use `uintptr_t` to deal with addresses as integers.

Comment: Function `ft_itoa_base()`  is unable to handle a `uintmax_t`.  Post its code.

Comment: @MikeCAT Since C99, As `uintptr_t` is an optional type, yet `uintmax_t` is required, what situation do your see where `uintptr_t` would handle dealing with object address as integers that `uintmax_t` would fail?   Certainly the range of `uintmax_t` meets/exceeds `uintptr_t`.  `uintmax_t` does have a matching print specifier, whereas `uintptr_t` does not.  OP would likely print a  `uintptr_t` casting to  `uintmax_t`.

Comment: "my function prints something like this: 58a2d2bb" is an incorrect value of the address.  "7fff" is simple part of the correct address that your alternative `ft_...()` code failed to handle.  To fix, first post a [mcve].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, thank you! Problem was with ft_itoa_base() . Dont know how I didn't see it, one of the variables was int instead of uintmax_t.

Comment: `ft_itoa_base()` can readily have other troubles too (I suspect sign-ness and insufficient buffer ones).  Posting that code would allow more than the `int` v. `uintmax_t` resolution.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica , added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does 0x7fff mean?

The missing "0x7fff" is part of the correct hexadecimal address lost in errant code of `ft_itoa_base()`.

OP's original `ft_itoa_base()` was not fully `uintmax_t` ready given [one of the variables was int instead of uintmax_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817593/what-does-0x7fff-mean-c-language?noredirect=1#comment111087328_62817593).

That caused the output to print a truncated address of "58a2d2bb" rather than the correct "7fff58a2d2bb".

---

The posted corrected `ft_itoa_base()` has minor weaknesses.

```
// char* ft_itoa_base(uintmax_t num, uintmax_t base) {
// No need for base to be so wide with uintmax_t
char* ft_itoa_base(uintmax_t num, int /* or unsigned */ base) {
  int i;
  uintmax_t val_cp;
  // uintmax_t rem;
  // No need for rem to be so wide with uintmax_t
  int /* or unsigned */ rem;
  char *str;

  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`0x7fff58a2d2bb` is `140,734,680,453,819` expressed in hexadecimal (or base 16) format where the digit `a` represents 10, `b` represents 11, and up to `f` which represents 15.

Base 16 or hexadecimal format is preferred over base 10 for memory addresses because 16 is a power of 2 which makes it handy for viewing as bit masks, and 10 is not which makes it difficult to view in terms of bit masks.